# Counting binary sequences with $S$ $0$'s and $T$ $1$'s where every pre-sequence contains fewer $1$'s than $0$'s

Tags: combinatorics

How many $S+T$-digit binary sequences with exactly $S$ $0$'s and $T$ $1$'s exist where in every pre-sequence the number of $1$'s is less than the number of $0$'s?

Examples:

- the sequence $011100$, is bad since the pre-sequence $011$ has more $1$'s than $0$'s.
- the sequence $010101000$, is good since there is no pre-sequence such that there are more $1$'s than $0$'s.

Comment: This may be related to [Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).

Comment: This is an expanding of Catalan number actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a famous problem often called [Bertand's Ballot Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem) A good summary is given in the Wikipedia article cited. There are a number of nice proofs.

Note that your statement is the classical one ("always ahead") but the example of a good sequence that you give shows that "never behind" is intended. If that is the case, go to the "ties allowed" section of the article. The number of good sequences turns out to be
$$\binom{s+t}{s}\frac{s+1-t}{s+1}.$$

Comment: I can't understand the how come the number of paths from (-1,1) to (p,q) is $\binom{p+q}{q-1}.$, Can you please explain the idea behind that?

Comment: To get from $(-1,1)$ to $(p,q)$ we need to take a total of $p+q$ steps, of which $1+p$ are to the right and $q-1$ are up. There are $\binom{p+q}{q-1}$ ways to decide which of the $p+q$ steps are up steps.

Comment: Got it, Thank you very much.